# Terraform:EKS -Cluster creation with ONLY Private Subnets

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, terraform-provider-azure

Requirement: Is to create EKS Cluster via Terraform with only Private subnets

```
     Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (eks-dev-cluster:ng_2) to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED',
     wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
        │   * subnet-******, subnet-******e5, subnet-******4: Ec2SubnetInvalidConfiguration: One or more Amazon EC2 Subnets of [subnet-*****, subnet-*****, subnet-*****] for node group ng_2 does not automatically assign public IP addresses to instances launched into it. 
If you want your instances to be assigned a public IP address, then you need to enable auto-assign public IP address for the subnet.
See IP addressing in VPC guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#subnet-public-ip
        │
        │   with aws_eks_node_group.eks_nodegroup["ng_2"],
        │   on eks-workers.tf line 9, in resource "aws_eks_node_group" "EKS_NG":
        │    9: resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks_nodegroup" {
```

I gave the `map_public_ip_on_launch = false`  as below

```
module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.11.0"
  create_vpc = var.create_vpc
  name = var.vpc_name
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr

  azs             = slice(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, 0, 3)
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets
  public_subnets  = var.public_subnets
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  enable_nat_gateway = var.enable_nat_gateway
  single_nat_gateway = var.single_nat_gateway
  enable_vpn_gateway = var.enable_vpn_gateway

  tags = {
    Name                                      = var.vpc_name
    Environment                               = terraform.workspace
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster-name}" = "shared"
  }
}
```

Also the error came out when running below file

###### eks-workers.tf

```
locals{
private_subnet_ids = var.create_vpc? module.vpc.private_subnets : tolist(data.aws_subnet_ids.private[0].ids)
}

# creating node groups

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "EKS_NG" {
  for_each = var.eks_node_groups
  cluster_name = aws_eks_cluster.ds-eks-airflow.name
  node_group_name =  each.key
  node_role_arn = var.create_role? aws_iam_role.ds-eks-airflow-node[0].arn : var.node_rolearn
  subnet_ids = local.private_subnet_ids
  instance_types = [each.value.instance_type]
  capacity_type =  each.value.capacity_type
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = each.value.desired_size
    max_size     = each.value.max_size
    min_size     = each.value.min_size
  }
  
  remote_access {
     ec2_ssh_key = each.value.ec2_ssh_key
     source_security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.ds-eks-airflow-node.id ]
  }
 
  tags = each.value.tags
  labels = each.value.labels
  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before EKS Node Group handling.

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
    aws_eks_cluster.ds-eks-airflow,
    aws_security_group.ds-eks-airflow-node
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case assign only private subnet to the node group, otherwise public subnet should have mapPublicIpOnLaunch set to true for EKS.

> If self-managed nodes are deployed to a public subnet, the subnet must
> be configured to auto-assign public IP addresses.
>
> If managed nodes are deployed to a public subnet, the subnet must be
> configured to auto-assign public IP addresses.

[Details](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html).

Comment: I have mentioned `map_public_ip_on_launch = false`

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Do you meant to say we need public subnets along with private subnets?

Comment: No, try think of an EC2 in fully private subnet.

Comment: @gohm'c did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into the same issue